# @reactivex/rxjs and rxjs NPM packages for RxJS 5

Tags: npm, rxjs, rxjs5

In [`@reactivex/rxjs` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reactivex/rxjs) it is suggested that scoped package should be used:

> npm install @reactivex/rxjs

And UMD module is available through npmcdn as

```
https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js
```

However, [unscoped `rxjs` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) has got published 5.x versions too but README also suggests

> npm install @reactivex/rxjs

And UMD module is available as

```
https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/bundles/Rx.umd.js
```

Both refer to `git+ssh://git@github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS.git` repository, but package contents look totally different.

Why do their trees differ so much? What is the practical difference between those two? Is there a reason why one of them should be favoured at this moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

doubled check **now** and they appears to be the same file

```
$ wget https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/bundles/Rx.umd.js -q -O rxjs
$ wget https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js -q -O reativx-rxjs
$ diff rxjs reativx-rxjs 
$
```

Comment: Yes, umds seem to be binary equal. But why their trees differ so much (the contents of `rxjs@latest` seem to be more chaotic), and which one should be added to the project to make it forward compatible?

Comment: i diged a bit more, it happens they have a real complex publish system. If you look carefully https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reactivex/rxjs. You ll see that to install the es6 version, they recommend `rxjs-es`, to install the commonjs `rxjs`, and for all versions `@reactivex/rxjs`. I believe you should use the most suitable version for your project, and that the difference you ve seen should be related to the version of the package it s being built for. if you have an example of difference we could verify that.

Comment: I see, so @reactivex/rxjs is a superset of non-scoped packages. Thanks, this sounds like a good answer to me.